# Swift 4 decode simple root level json value

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

According to the JSON standard [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-3), this is valid json:

```
22
```

How do I decode this into an Int using swift4's decodable? This does not work

```
let twentyTwo = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Int.self, from: "22".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: this is not a valid json, a json is made by key and value pairs and it's just a value.

Comment: This is valid JSON fragment, not valid JSON.

Comment: I guess it depends on the standard one is using. Check out RFC 7159 here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. also source that it is valid https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-3

Comment: If you wrap your `try` in a `Do..Catch` and handle the error, it will tell you that your json format is not correct. That is not a valid JSON, why are you insisting on this?

Comment: JSONSerialization has a [allowFragments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization.readingoptions/1416042-allowfragments) reading option for that purpose, but the new JSONDecoder has no such option.

Comment: @Desdenova I am not insisting, it is valid according to the RFC 7159 standard which is definitely being used widely. If what you are saying is true I guess this means swift is not using it though.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR I'm not able to find a way to use this, I will investigate further i guess

Comment: @saph, aren't JSONDecoder follows [RFC 4627](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627)?

Comment: I would tend to agree with you @user28434, I can't find a source on this though

Comment: @saph, well `RFC 7159` is pretty young standard (~3 years), `JSONSerialization` first appeared before 2014, and I bet `JSONDecoder` is just a wrapper around `JSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It works with good ol' `JSONSerialization` and the `.allowFragments`
reading option. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization.readingoptions/1416042-allowfragments):

> `allowFragments`
>
> Specifies that the parser should allow top-level objects that are not an instance of NSArray or NSDictionary.

Example:

```
let json = "22".data(using: .utf8)!

if let value = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: .allowFragments)) as? Int {
    print(value) // 22
}
```

However, `JSONDecoder` has no such option and does not accept top-level
objects which are not arrays or dictionaries. One can see in the
[source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L1107) that the `decode()` method calls
`JSONSerialization.jsonObject()` without any option:

```
open func decode<T : Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T {
    let topLevel: Any
    do {
       topLevel = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    } catch {
        throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: error))
    }

    // ...

    return value
}
```

Comment: You can try and file a bug report at Apple.

Comment: I forgot to write, this but I submitted an issue here https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6163

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 13.1+ and macOS 10.15.1+ `JSONDecoder` can handle *primitive* types on root level.

See the latest comments (Oct 2019) in the linked article underneath Martin's answer.