# Allow fragments with JSONDecoder?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, json-deserialization

I'm working with an API that for certain endpoints will return a single string as a JSON response, wrapped in double quotes, like so:

> "The Response"

[This is valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/?json=%22The%20Response%22), even though the top level or root object is neither an array, nor a dictionary.

Before Swift 4 one would decode JSON using [`JSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization). Swift 4 introduces [`JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder). The former could be coaxed into allowing fragments, with the [`.allowFragments` reading option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization.readingoptions/1416042-allowfragments). I'm at a loss to find something similar for the `JSONDecoder`. It has the concept of a [`SingleValueDecodingContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/singlevaluedecodingcontainer), but I can't figure out how to have it work on the root object of a JSON. JSONDecoder simply refuses to decode it.

To illustrate this, consider the following code (you can copy & paste it into a blank Xcode Playground):

```
import Foundation

let response = "\"The Response\""
let responseData = response.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    print("JSONDecoder")
    let value = try JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: responseData)
    print("Success: \(value)")
} catch {
    print("Failure: \(error)")
}

print("")

do {
    print("JSONSerialization")
    let value = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .allowFragments)
    print("Success: \(value)")
} catch {
    print("Failure: \(error)")
}
```

This will print the following to the console:

> JSONDecoder
>   Failure: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))
>
> JSONSerialization
>   Success: The Response

As expected, `JSONSerialization` can deserialize the response, but `JSONDecoder` can't. And it even says it in the error message, `option to allow fragments not set` – but how do I set that option?

Who knows how to use JSONDecoder with a non-array, non-dictionary root element?

Cheers,
EP

P.S. JSONSerialization didn't yet get deprecated, so I know I can write my Swift 4 code in ways that uses that one instead of JSONDecoder to decode API responses, but I would rather stick to a single way of processing API responses.

Comment: JSONDecoder does not have such an "allowFragments" option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768535/swift-4-decode-simple-root-level-json-value.

Comment: Yup, this is a solid dupe then. Thanks!