# Swift 4: JSONDecoder fails in one specific case - "The operation could not be completed"

Tags: json, swift, decode, codable, jsondecoder

I am receiving JSON text, converting it to Data, and then using JSONDecoder to create a concrete type represented by the JSON text/string.

It does work with my "complex" data structure (which implements Codable), or even a simple array of Int as shown below:

```
import Foundation

let jsonTextContainigArrayOfInt: String = "[1,2,3]"
let data = jsonTextContainigArrayOfInt.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let arrayOfInt: [Int] = try JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: data)
    for n in arrayOfInt {
        print(n)
    }
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The previous code works and correctly creates the array of Int and prints them.

The problem occurs when doing this same approach with a single Int in the JSON-text:

```
import Foundation

let jsonTextContainigOneInt: String = "1"
let data = jsonTextContainigOneInt.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let myInt: Int = try JSONDecoder().decode(Int.self, from: data)
    print(myInt)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

For this second approach, I get the following error:

> "The operation could not be completed"

***** Edit *****

Bug report for this already exists: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6163

Comment: "1" is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your time picciano. Could you comment on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7487892/8284660. It states that values such as a single string should be valid now (in RFC 7159)

Comment: Since (NS)JSONSerialization doesn't accept it, it wouldn't surprise at all that JSONDecoder too. See the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization?language=objc Also, it seems that its RFC 4627 compliant only, not the new one (https://github.com/gnustep/libs-base/blob/master/Source/NSJSONSerialization.m)

Comment: Use `JSONSerialization`, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941826/allow-fragments-with-jsondecoder?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you both! I did see that JSONSerialization doesn't accept non-array, non-dictionary objects as valid JSON even though (as I told @picciano), in RFC-7159, it is now valid JSON. I now see that JSONDecoder doesn't have a ".allowFragments" option as in JSONSerialization. Thanks for the clarification @schmidt9.

Comment: Thank you all for the time!

Answer (score 1):

`JSONDecoder` can only decode a collection type (array or dictionary) as root object.

Under the hood `JSONDecoder` uses `JSONSerialization` **without** any options. However to decode a `String` or `Int` you have to specify the `.allowFragments` option.

Use `JSONSerialization` with the `.allowFragments` option

```
let jsonTextContainingOneString = "1"
let data = Data(jsonTextContainingOneString.utf8)

do {
    let myString = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
    print(myString)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... I found this:

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/JSONSerialization.swift#L120

Specifically this guard statement:

```
open class JSONSerialization : NSObject {
        //...

        // top level object must be an Swift.Array or Swift.Dictionary
        guard obj is [Any?] || obj is [String: Any?] else {
            return false
        }

        //...
}
```

Then I looked if a simple text-string should be considered valid JSON, and apparently it should now (it was previously not accepted as valid JSON). At least, based on this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7487892/8284660

This makes me wonder whether or not the behavior on my original post should be a bug or not.

Comment: Bug report already exists: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6163