# Decode a JSON object escaped in a String

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode, codable

I get a response from an API (unfortunately, I cannot change it) that looks something like (just an example):

As bytes => `"{\"key\":\"value\"}"`

The starting and ending quotes and the escaped quotes are all part of the response, I am solving it in a really ugly way that looks like this:

```
// (...) Receiving response

guard var responseString = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
    print("Response wasn't just a string, great!") // unfortunately, this never happens
    return
}
responseString = responseString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) // make sure it is trimmed
responseString = String(responseString.dropFirst()) // drop the quote at the start
responseString = String(responseString.dropLast()) // drop the quote at the end
responseString = responseString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\"", with: "\"")// convert all \" to " (and hope nothing else is escaped <<< this is really bad!!!)
let responseDataToDecode = responseString.data(using: .utf8)!

// (...) decoding with JSONDecoder
```

Is there a way to automatically unescape the string and use the JSON object that is contained in it?

Comment: It is a valid JSON string

Comment: Oh, it's a JSON encoded twice! Oh my god.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the problem

Comment: Please show us the actual data as a string as displayed by NSLog. Give us some real data to bang our heads on. :)

Comment: JSON withing JSON? Use JSONSerialization and use `.allowFragments`, then convert it into Data back, and then use JSONDecoder()? Ok, that's strange. Else https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941826/allow-fragments-with-jsondecoder?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, I meant to create any kind of object as example, corrected.

Comment: Here is some example (that's calling too many times JSONSerialization in my opinion, but..). https://pastebin.com/GBSBTpPK

Comment: Also give the criminal who produced this double JSON a good kicking.

Comment: The worst part is that I told the guy that he could improve his BE by sending JSON objects instead of strings and he got quite angry and told me JSONs are always strings 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's double-encoded, then you just need to double-decode. If I understand correctly, the incoming data is like this:

```
let str = #""{\"key\":\"value\"}""#
// "{\\"key\\":\\"value\\"}"
```

The first byte is `"`, the second byte is `{`, the third byte is `\`, the fourth byte is `"`.

That's a JSON-encoded string. So decode that as a string (there was a time when this didn't work because it's a "fragment," but it works fine currently, at least in all my tests):

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let string = try! decoder.decode(String.self, from: Data(str.utf8)) // {"key":"value"}
```

And then decode that as your type (`[String:String]` just for example):

```
let result = try! decoder.decode([String:String].self, from: Data(string.utf8))
// ["key": "value"]
```

(IMO this kind of double-encoding is fine, BTW, and I'm not sure why there are so many comments against it. Serializing an arbitrary object makes a lot more sense in many cases than forcing the schema to deal with an arbitrary structure. As long as it's cleanly encoded, I don't see any problem here.)

Comment: _there was a time when this didn't work because it's a "fragment"_ I think that time was iOS 12 and before, though I may be wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a first step: You need an official documented statement what exactly the format of your data is. It looks like someone took some data, turned it into JSON data, interpreted the data as a string, and then converted the string to a JSON fragment. It's not difficult to decode the JSON fragment, getting a string, turning the string into data, and decoding that data as JSON (starting with JSONSerialization and .allowFragments, probably the only time you should use .allowFragments in your life). Doing it without swearing is hard.

But first you want in writing that this is actually the format. Because I would bet that whoever is responsible for that data format will eventually change it without telling you and break your code.