# String values cannot be encoded when app is running on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, encoding, codable

I have written this func to save codable objects in my keychain store. I passed a String API key to this func as the value and in 13+ iOS versions it works perfectly fine.

```
class StoreManager {
     public static func save<T: Codable>(_ value: T, forKey key: String) {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value) else { 
           return 
        }
        try? keychain.set(data, key: key)
     }
}


let dummyApiKey = "1234567=8+90"
StoreManager().save(dummyApiKey, forKey: "id")
```

In iOS 12 though, somehow the String value cannot be encoded, and the guard statement goes into return. Does anyone know what's different in iOS 12 that makes it impossible to encode?

Comment: Start by doing a real `do`/`try`/`catch` instead of `try`, it could explain why it fails...

Comment: The error would be then `Error: invalidValue("1234567=8+90", Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Top-level String encoded as string JSON fragment.", underlyingError: nil))`. "String" being a Valid JSON needs fragment (that's why there is that parameter in old `JSONSerialization`). Some explaination: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257242/jsonencoder-wont-allow-type-encoded-to-primitive-value and workaround, using `JSONSerialization` that can have the `.allowFragment` param.

Comment: @Larme "The data couldn’t be written because it isn’t in the correct format" thats the error that was caught.

Comment: You printed `error.localizedDescription` instead of `error`. `error.localizedDescription` is for user, not developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't debug yourself, **NEVER USE** `try?`. With more experience, I'd say that we tend to not use `try?`, but sometimes we do. But when we write `try?`, we are able to find an possible issue, ie debug if needed.

Let's do a proper try then, with a do/catch:

```
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(value)
    print(data)
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

And read the output.
Also, don't output `error.localizedDescription` which is more intented for the user, not the developer, output `error`.

The output is:

```
Error: invalidValue("1234567=8+90", 
                    Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [], 
                    debugDescription: "Top-level String encoded as string JSON fragment.", 
                    underlyingError: nil))
```

In other words:
A JSON is 99% of the time a `Dictionary` or an `Array` at top level, in Codable wording, it's a Codable struct with its property or an array of it.
But, some JSON reference allow a simple `String` to be JSON valid.
I guess it's been allowed with `JSONEncoder` in iOS13+ (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257242/jsonencoder-wont-allow-type-encoded-to-primitive-value))
In iOS, it's a `fragment`. The option is available with older `JSONSerialization` but not with `JSONEncoder`.

```
let data = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: [.fragmentsAllowed])
```

Now, you can use `@available(iOS 13, *)` to call either `JSONEncoder` or `JSONSerialization`:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    //Do the JSONEncoder thing
} else {
    //Do the JSONSerialization Thing
}
```

**Disclaimer:**
The start of the answer with the `try?` is a copy/paste from another of MY OWN [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69002191/1801544). So no plagiarism.